# npm package for identifying image morphology closing

Tags: node.js, image, npm, scikit-image, image-morphology

I am looking for some npm package which can decompose an image into outlines of objects in that image with each object programmatically identifiable (e.g. can be accessed by index or id or by some other method). A module with similar functionality is `skimage.morphology.closing`, but it's for Python.

Any help/hint is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Actually using [node-dv](https://github.com/creatale/node-dv) ,it use leptonica library to make image operations like opening and closing.